# Mysql, Doctrine 1.2 an a complicated Join query

Tags: mysql, join, doctrine

I am working with a configuration system that will save some parameters for various platforms in a mysql database.  The tables are this `settings(id, desc, value), settings_overrides(id, settings_id, value, platform_id), platform (id, platform_key, platform_desc).`

What I am looking for is a way to get all the values from settings, and only those values from overrides where platofrm_key is = to 'some vlaue'

So I have the joins figured out, just not sure the best way to bring this together.  AT this point what I am able to get is only values from all tables were platform_key='some value' But that isn't what I am looking for. Any thoughts?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

One of the ways to do that is to use a LEFT JOIN and CASE statement in SELECT. For example:

```
select
  id,
  desc,
  case so.value when NULL then s.value else so.value end case as setting_value
from settings s
left join settings_overrides so on so.settings_id = s.id and platform_key = 'some value'
```